How to create a high resolution 2D Power Spectrum Estimates for Procedural Noise?
I'm currently trying to produce a 2D Power Spectrum Estimate for Perlin noise. An example of this can be found on page 15 of Survey Procedural Noise. The images in row (4) are what I'm trying to recreate; specifically the leftmost row (4) image which is a power spectrum estimate of Perlin noise.
The issue I'm having is as I increase the scale of the Perlin noise (which increases the resolution/detail of values between 0 and 1) the power spectrum estimate becomes smaller in resolution, regardless of the size of the periodograms using Bartlett's method of power spectrum estimation.
Examples of how scale effects the Perlin noise (the resolution here is 100 to make the effect more noticable; I also can't embed yet, sorry):
Scale 2, Scale 8, Scale 32
Examples of how the power spectrum estimate "shrinks":
Scale 2 - Resolution 800 - Number of Periodograms 16,
Scale 8 - Resolution 3200 - Number of Periodograms 16,
Scale 32 - Resolution 12800 - Number of Periodograms 16
What I don't quite understand is why the power spectrum estimate gets smaller as the noise's scale increases even though the resolution of the noise and individual periodograms increases with the scale (my best guess is that it has something to do with the fft2d, but I do not understand why at all). (Also, to clarify, I will be using a much higher resolution and preferably a scale of 32 when calculating the actual power spectrum estimation)
Below is the code for my implementation of Bartlett's method for 2D power spectrums in python:
import numpy as np

def compute_periodogram(noise):
    fft_result = np.fft.fft2(noise)
    fft_shifted = np.fft.fftshift(fft_result)
    power_spectrum = np.abs(fft_shifted)**2

    return power_spectrum

# Computes Bartlett's power spectrum estimation for a 2D signal (assumes the 2D signal is a square)
def bartlett_2d(signal, k):
    periodograms = []

    k_1d = int(np.sqrt(k)) # Makes k (the number of subsections) 1D
    m = int(len(signal)/k) # Length of each subsection of the signal

    # Divides the signal into subsections and computes a peridogram for each subsection
    for y in range(k_1d):
        for x in range(k_1d):
            # `slice_2d` returns a slice of a 2d array (matrix, x_slice[start, end], y_slice[start, end])
            subsection = slice_2d(signal, (m*x, m*(x+1)-1),  (m*y, m*(y+1)-1))
            periodograms.append(compute_periodogram(subsection))
    
    # Averages peridograms
    power_spectrum = np.zeros((m, m))

    for pdg in periodograms:
        power_spectrum += pdg
    
    return power_spectrum / k

If anyone has advice on where I've gone wrong, how to improve this, or a better way of solving this problem, please let me know. Any help is appreciated.
